# Block editor: How to check if block editor has initialized and populated the data store?

Tags: javascript, wp-admin, block-editor

Within some JavaScript I have to get the current post content of Gutenberg. I am accessing this from jQuery (might be bad practice, however):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           const { select } = wp.data;
           var currentPost = select("core/editor").getCurrentPost();
});
```

Within this construct the content of `currentPost` is `undefined`.

Within:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
           const { select } = wp.data;
           var currentPost = select("core/editor").getCurrentPost();
        }, 3000);
});
```

`currentPost` is populated with everything I need.

As `setTimeout` is always a desperate solution I am asking you kindly for the correct callback/way to start a certain process as soon as Gutenberg is fully initialized?

Comment: `getCurrentPost` will not account for updates made to the content

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes I have already heard about this, but it is the easiest way to get the content in the beginning or after an update. Still this question is not exclusivley to to getCurrentPost() - this is also for almost any other functions e.g. getBlocks. Just correct me in case I go wrong somewhere.

Comment: There's better ways of acquiring the post content and staying up to date, you already know how to retrieve the blocks, just pass them through the serialize function to get the final string

Comment: @TomJNowell This is the better way to do it. Still getBlocks() does not retrieve any blocks until the block editor is fully loaded. So I still wonder how to find out when the block editor is fully loaded instead of using a timeout, maybe you know  how?